# Can I do this with autolayout/size classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6, ios-autolayout

Can I  do this with autolayout and size-classes in xcode 6 , and, if so, how do I accomplish it ?

The view should have aspect ratio 7:6 and the 4 buttons should appear as is shown in below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Yes, for some hours.

Comment: So you should give details and explain what didn't work

Comment: @Wain, I can create the large view with the desired aspect ratio. And I can create buttons below it (assuming portrait mode), but I can not space them equally. And, my bigger problem,  I cannot make the same buttons appear to the right of the large view in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size classes are not based on a specific size (i.e. < 300 pts == compact), but rather devices and specific orientations.  Because of that, you won't have the fine grained control I assume you want.

However, if you're okay giving up some control, you simply change the simulated size class in interface builder, setup your constraints, and they just work at run-time.

[image]

Comment: @ragnarius If you setup the layout constraints how you'd like in "Any/Any" simulated size, then switch to "Any/Compact" or "Large/Any" and relayout with the "landscape" layout, it'll just work at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM
its very easy, see the video :) Only you can do in iphone, for ipad no identify landscape or portrait orientation

Comment: I have seen that already... I like her video, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: you can do it with these video, first you select a size (compact | any) create a view. second you must select  (any | compact) and create other view with the button in other side, when you set iphone in landscape the view will change with the button to right and when you set portrait the buttons will be set to the bottom

Comment: I have tried this but I had two problems: When I changed the design-mode from "compact|any" to "any|compact" the buttons disappeared. That is to say, I could not use the same button objects in both design-modes. The other  problem was that I could not space the button equally. Is that possible in interface builder?

Comment: You need to place elements on any/any at first, then you can use then in any other design modes. To space buttons equally add constraints: 1) aspect ratio 1:1 to each button; 2) Equal width for each button 3) Constraints for space between buttons

Comment: yes the buttons disappear when change the view, you must add two collections of buttons. in this case you can set the same IBACTION in two uibuttons

Comment: see this, maybe help http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/

Comment: @Ghostnars, and how about outlets. Let's say I would like to disable a button from code. Would that be a problem if I had two collections of buttons?

Comment: @VladimirK , Thanks, I see how to space equally